# dialog list lotus notes in xpages

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

Is there any equivalent for lotus notes `Dialog list` in xpages? Or, if it's possible, an xpage `combobox` ''which accepts'' multiple values selected.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `xe:djextListTextBox` to collect and show multiple values, use `xe:valuePicker` to add values from an existing list to ListTextBox and use optionally a `button` to prompt for a new value and to add it to ListTextBox.

This is an example for `xe:djextListTextBox` and `xe:valuePicker`:

```xml
   <xe:djextListTextBox
      id="djextListTextBox1"
      multipleSeparator=","
      multipleTrim="true"
      defaultValue="abc,def"
      value="#{viewScope.test}">
   </xe:djextListTextBox>
   <xe:valuePicker
      id="valuePicker1"
      for="djextListTextBox1"
      pickerText="Add">
      <xe:this.dataProvider>
         <xe:simpleValuePicker>
            <xe:this.valueList><![CDATA[#{javascript:
               ["abc","def","ghj","klm","nop","xyz"]
            }]]></xe:this.valueList>
         </xe:simpleValuePicker>
      </xe:this.dataProvider>
   </xe:valuePicker>
```

[image]

I like this approach as it is for the user easy to add and to delete values and it looks good.

An *alternative* is the combination of `xp:inputText` and `xe:valuePicker`:

```xml
   <xp:inputText
      id="inputText1"
      multipleSeparator=","
      value="#{viewScope.test}"
      defaultValue="abc,def">
   </xp:inputText>
   <xe:valuePicker
      id="valuePicker1"
      for="inputText1">
      <xe:this.dataProvider>
         <xe:simpleValuePicker>
            <xe:this.valueList><![CDATA[#{javascript:
               ["abc","def","ghj","klm","nop","xyz"]
            }]]></xe:this.valueList>
         </xe:simpleValuePicker>
      </xe:this.dataProvider>
   </xe:valuePicker>
```

[image]

Users can add their own new values as the InputText field is editable. This approach might be a good solution if new values are allowed and users know how to edit values considering the multiple separator.

In case you'd like to have each value in a *separate line* you can use `xe:djTextarea` and set multipleSeparator to newline:

```xml
   <xe:djTextarea
      id="djTextarea1"
      multipleSeparator="#{javascript:'\n'}"
      value="#{viewScope.test}"
      defaultValue="#{javascript:['abc','def']}"
      cols="30">
   </xe:djTextarea>
   <xe:valuePicker
      id="valuePicker1"
      for="djTextarea1">
      <xe:this.dataProvider>
         <xe:simpleValuePicker>
            <xe:this.valueList><![CDATA[#{javascript:
               ["abc","def","ghj","klm","nop","xyz"]
            }]]></xe:this.valueList>
         </xe:simpleValuePicker>
      </xe:this.dataProvider>
   </xe:valuePicker>
```

[image]

The text box grows and shrinks with the number of selected values automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The List Text Box element, should I find it in the Extension Library section? ;/

Comment: It's the control "Dojo List Text Box" in Extension Library part "Dojo Form"

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try and let you know if it works ( Of course it works : ) but I hope I can make it )

Comment: how I insert a multiple Separator for the editbox/listbox as I want my selected to be displayed in new lines? I tried adding a computed value: "\n" but it doesn't works. Thank you

Comment: Great answer! I highly recommend that @MFG Flay load and study the extension library samples from OpenNTF. Even if you do not use the OpenNTF version, the samples DB shows how lots of the controls work.

Comment: I added a version with new line as separator. I think, you have all features similar to classic Notes Dialog List now and can develop the things you want.

Answer (score 0):

The ValuePicker control in the Extension Library provides the Dialog List functionality, but not with the "Allow values not in list" functionality.