# Set height for dojo text area in xpages

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I have a dojo text area which I'm binding it to a field. I saw that on browser, its height is OK but if I open the xpage in the Notes client its height is twice bigger. I tried adding `height` property for the text area, but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The third example of http://stackoverflow.com/a/23109307/2065611 does work in XPiNC (in Notes Client) - it has exactly the size of the text in it. How does your code look like and what Notes version you are on?

Comment: <xe:djTextarea id="djTextarea1"
     value="#{frmDoc.txt_autor}" style="width:200px;line-height:90%;"
     showReadonlyAsDisabled="true">
    </xe:djTextarea>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers Firefox and XPiNC (XPages in Notes Client - that is XULrunner based on Firefox) show Dojo Text Area (dijit.form.Textarea) always with at least **two rows** even it contains only one line of text.

[image]

Other browsers like Chrome and IE work like expected.

[image]

You don't have a chance to change that behavior with style "height"/"minHeight" or parameter "rows".

The only solution I found is [to create an own Textarea widget](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/dijit-form-Textarea-w-only-1-row-in-Firefox-td3994249.html). But I am not sure if it's worth it...

This issue shows up only for contents with one line. As soon as you have two or more text lines Dojo Text Area's height adapts exactly - for all browsers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height using css styles,  that should do it.
Update:
In case css should not be working here try using the classic HTML attributes 'cols' and 'rows'. I don't have Domino Designer ata hand right now,  so I can't tell whether those attributes are available. If not you could add them yourself using the 'attrs' group.

Comment: I tried with height and also with line-height:90% but in Lotus client it doesn't work. On browser it does.